# Disabling keypress events for all the forms but Active one with js

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with JQM, when if I hit enter, it submits all the forms instead of active one, so I wrote this code to disable ENTER key for all the forms:

```
$('body').keypress(function (evt) {      
  var charCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode == 13 && !$(evt.target).is("textarea")) { //Enter key's keycode
    return false;
   }
});
```

but how to disable a keypress for all the forms, but a current one? let say it has id="activeOne". So I want to work Enter to for for activeOne, but not other? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. On every form click or keypress event just set the form id into a variable and check for that inside `body` `keypress` event and act accordingly.

```
var currentFormId;
$('form').bind('click, keypress', function(){
    currentFormId = this.id;
});

$('body').keypress(function (evt) {      
  //Enter key's keycode
  if (evt.which == 13 
      && !$(evt.target).closest("form").is('#'+currentFormId)) { 
    return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood clearly, but from what I understood below code should do the trick,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/e6m25/2/) here - Enter Key will work only on 2nd textbox.

```
$('body').keypress(function (evt) {    
    var activeElement = document.activeElement;
    if ($(activeElement).closest('form').attr('id') == 'active') {
        return true;
    }  else {
       var charCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
       if (charCode == 13 && !$(evt.target).is("textarea")) { //Enter key's keycode
           return false;
       }
   }
});
```